# Erro SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 No Magento 2 quando tento rodar o comando magento:upgrade

Tags: mysql, query, table, magento

Estou trabalhando em um ecommerce com base no Magento 2 e após tentar instalar um módulo relacionado ao campo CEP do cadastro o comando upgrade do magento ( bin/magento setup:upgrade ) me retorna o seguinte erro:

```
Base table or view not found: 1146 Table  
'justme41_mage535.mgja_magedev_brazil_zipcode' doesn't exist, query  
was: SHOW CREATE TABLE `mgja_magedev_brazil_zipcode`
```

Alguém já passou por algo parecido e consegue me auxiliar?

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045). Veja [ask] e faça o nosso [tour].

Answer (score -2):

Basta excluir as tabelas que mostram com erro direto no banco de dados, pode ser feito através do cpanel - phpmyadmin e ir executando o comando via ssh -

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).